# What is the difference between data validation types in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel you can choose between data validation:

- Whole number
- Decimal
- List
- Date
- Time
- Text length
- Custom

Apart from List and custom all other data validation is done on some form of number. Dates and time is stored as a number in Excel. So would it be correct to say that there internally in excel is no difference between the validation functions used for whole number, decimal, date, time and text length?

Or is there a logical difference between these types which I'm not picking up on?

Answer (score 1):

> So would it be correct to say that there internally in excel is no
>   difference between the validation functions used for Whole number,
>   decimal, date, time and text length?

Not really. While it is true that in the cell those will all be 'numbers' behind the scenes the validation is important to restrict how they are entered (and used). Not to mention you can add additional checks like range or time frame. It's to ensure that the user enters data in an expected format.

Whole numbers validation will prevent a user from entering a real number (no . or , depending on culture). Decimal will allow real numbers. Date and time also must follow the format rules for the current culture for those types.

More info [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/apply-data-validation-to-cells-HA102749059.aspx)